# "cannot open Read/Write handles"

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, intel-fortran

What causes the error "cannot open Read/Write handles" in Visual Studio 2013?
I am using it with Intel Parallel Studio XE 2016. It works for a few days after the installation but suddenly when I'm trying to open a project this error comes.

Comment: Welcome. See [tour] and [ask]. What exactly are you doing? Where are you clicking where it happens? Does it happen for all projects? Tell us the details.

Comment: Well, I am using Intel fortran integrated with VS 2013. Everything was ok until today when I tried to open an existing project (any project) or even create a new project but it exits the VS with the aforementioned error. I tried to repair installations of both Intel Fortran compiler and VS itself, but the error remains.

Comment: I recommend you to contact the Intel technical support forum.